# Extracting data from a column using mysqli::bind_result()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

My query returns with null in my php code , but when I enter the same query into phpmyadmin it returns the row to which it belongs. Here is the database I am using

```
CREATE TABLE `payment`.`users`(
`u_id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`passwd` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

and here is the code i am using that is returning null when it clearly works in phpmyadmin.

```
function getUserId($email, $passwd) {
 $mysqli = db_connect();

 $query = "SELECT `u_id` FROM `payment`.`users` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `passwd`='$passwd' ORDER BY 1";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($u_id);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        return $u_id;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the code that you use to call `getUserId()`. I strongly suspect you are not passing the data you think you're passing. Also, you are leaving yourself wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: By the way, you really should reuse your connection, not create (and abandon) a connection each time you call this function.

Comment: getUserId('test@gmail.com', '123456')

Comment: I am well aware of the sql injection btw

Comment: @user3288619 can you paste down the exact query you run in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: SELECT `u_id` FROM `payment`.`users` WHERE `email`='test@gmail.com' AND `passwd`='123456' . this is the query

Answer (score -1):

The thing is that you are using variables in your php code to set the values. In phpMyAdmin you're inserting values directly, therefore the problem may be in the values inserted.

First of all use ***PDO***'s [bindParam()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or ***mysqli***'s [bind_param()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) statements as they sanitize inputs and help you avoid [SQL Injections](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).
Second good thing about using prepared statements and binding params is that you can specify the type of the data being binded to to the query which in most cases will fix such problems. Though in your case you're probably inserting strings.

Comment: Basically i forgot to put the sha1(). The sql injections are the least of my cancern , this isnt going anywhere public. 

original: $query = "SELECT `u_id` FROM `payment`.`users` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `passwd`='$passwd' ORDER BY 1";

fixed: $query = "SELECT `u_id` FROM `payment`.`users` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `passwd`=sha1('$passwd') ORDER BY 1";

Comment: hmm.. but what was the actual problem? in both cases '$passwd' or sha1('$passwd') are strings??

Comment: yeah i fixed it . before i sent the password into the database i wrapped it in a sha1 encrypter. so to retrieve it i would have to decrypt it. just a minor mistake

Comment: How does it answer the question?